# Where clause to filter results of certain selected data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm looking to find out how I can filter the data results of a query, using a special where clause if a certain location.  It's hard to explain what i'm looking to do in words, but here is my example:

I have a query that pulls results from a series of locations:

```
    Select a.Location, a.Invoice_date, a.service, a.QTY, b.user
    From Invoice_detail as a inner join Invoice_tb as b on 
           a.invoice_number = b.invoice_number and a.location = b.location
    where invoice_date between @startdate and @enddate and Not (a.location = 1 and a.service = 1)
    order by a.location
```

This gives me the following output:

```
Location            Invoice Date        Service     QTY    User
   1                 1/2/16               1          1      Tim
   1                 1/2/16               1          1      Bob
   1                 1/2/16               1          1      Tim
   1                 1/2/16               2          1      Bob                        
   1                 1/2/16               3          1      Bob 
   2                 1/2/16               1          1      Tim
   2                 1/2/16               2          1      Bob
   2                 1/2/16               4          1      Tim
   3                 1/2/16               1          1      Bob
   3                 1/2/16               6          1      Tim
   3                 1/2/16               1          1      Bob
```

I would like to NOT return Service '1' if the location is '1'.  But I DO want to return service 1 for any other location.  So I would like my output to look like this:

```
Location            Invoice Date        Service     QTY    User
   1                 1/2/16               2          1      Bob                        
   1                 1/2/16               3          1      Bob 
   2                 1/2/16               1          1      Tim
   2                 1/2/16               2          1      Bob
   2                 1/2/16               4          1      Tim
   3                 1/2/16               1          1      Bob
   3                 1/2/16               6          1      Tim
   3                 1/2/16               1          1      Bob
```

Comment: Can't you just add the condition `AND NOT(Service = 1 AND Location = 1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `AND NOT(Service = 1 AND Location = 1)` in your `WHERE` conditions:

```
SELECT 
    a.Location, 
    a.Invoice_date, 
    a.service, 
    a.QTY, 
    b.[user]
FROM Invoice_detail AS a 
INNER JOIN Invoice_tb AS b 
    ON a.invoice_number = b.invoice_number 
    AND a.location = b.location
WHERE 
    invoice_date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
    AND NOT(a.service = 1 AND a.Location = 1)
ORDER BY a.location
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/443973)</kbd>

Comment: This doesn't work, i'm not sure if it's because I have am using Joins and you're not in your demo?

Comment: It does not matter if `JOIN` is used since the columns in the conditions are coming from the main table (the one in the `FROM`).

Comment: That doesn't work for me.  I still get anything with service 1 at location 1.

Comment: @Shmewnix, that's weird. What's the datatype of `Service` and `Location`?